# yocto do_unpack() - same directory names in different layers

Tags: yocto, bitbake

During experiments with Yocto's [Advanced Kernel Metadata](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/kernel-dev/advanced.html) I got into a situation where I would like to have the `.scc`, `.patch` and `.cfg` files organized into a directory structure as mentioned in the [syntax](https://docs.yoctoproject.org/kernel-dev/advanced.html#kernel-metadata-syntax) section, and to keep that structure in all the layers (consider 2 layers here - `meta-main_layer` and `meta-bsp_layer`):

```
meta-main_layer
└── recipes-kernel
    └── linux
        └── linux-yocto.bb
        └── linux-yocto
            ├── cfg
            │   ├── main_frag_1.cfg
            │   └── main_frag_1.scc
            ├── features
            │   ├── main_feature_1.cfg
            │   ├── main_feature_1.patch
            │   └── main_feature_1.scc
            └── patches
                ├── main_patch_1.patch
                └── main_patch_1.scc
meta-bsp_layer
└── recipes-kernel
    └── linux
        └── linux-yocto.bbappend
        └── linux-yocto
            ├── bsp
            │   └── bsp_definition.scc
            ├── cfg
            │   ├── bsp_frag_1.cfg
            │   └── bsp_frag_1.scc
            ├── features
            │   ├── bsp_feature_1.cfg
            │   ├── bsp_feature_1.patch
            │   └── bsp_feature_1.scc
            └── patches
                ├── bsp_patch_1.patch
                └── bsp_patch_1.scc
```

`meta-main_layer/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto.bb` contains:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}:"
...
SRC_URI = "file://linux-yocto;type=kmeta \
       "
```

**Edit:**

And `meta-bsp_layer/recipes-kernel/linux/linux-yocto.bbappend`:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}:"
...
SRC_URI += " file://linux-yocto;type=kmeta \
       "
```

**... end of edit**

This means that after parsing the recipes, the `SRC_URI` will contain `file://linux-yocto;type=kmeta` twice, and `FILESEXTRAPATHS=meta-bsp_layer/recipes-kernel/linux:meta-main_layer/recipes-kernel/linux:`. The way I understand it, the `do_unpack()` task goes through the files in `SRC_URI` and for each of them, it searches `FILESEXTRAPATHS` for that file, and it takes the first one it finds. That means that in my case, only the files from `meta-bsp_layer` are taken, as its path is the first in `FILESEXTRAPATHS`, and the files from the `meta-main_layer` are ignored.

What I would like to achieve is that instead of taking the files from only the first path found in `FILESEXTRAPATHS`, `do_unpack()` would go through all of the paths in `FILESEXTRAPATHS` and merge the directories of the same name (`cfg`, `features` and `patches`) from both layers. Without that, I don't see any big benefits of using the Advanced Kernel Metadata mechanism. Could anyone advise how to get this done?

PS: I'm using Yocto Zeus.

Comment: My first comment on this is that even if you have 1000 layers that append to `linux-yocto` recipe, `do_unpack` MUST unpack all of their `SRC_URI` entry into `${WORKDIR}` of `linux-yocto` , so to do that, you should append to `SRC_URI` and not override it with `=` , so in both of `meta-bsp_layer` and `meta-main_layer` use `SRC_URI_append = " file://...`

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my question, I edited it - the `.bbappend` file doesn't assign into `SRC_URI` with `=`, but appends with `+=`.  My understanding is that that's the same as using `_append`?
I tried to use `SRC_URI_append` in both `.bb` and `.bbappend`, but the behavior is still the same - the `SRC_URI` and `FILESEXTRAPATHS` variables after parsing the recipe are as described in the second to last paragraph in my question, and `${WORKDIR}` only contains the files and directories from the layer that occurs in `FILESEXTRAPATHS` first.